# Grails upgrade from 2.5.1 to 3.1.4

Tags: grails, grails-orm

While migrating my grails 2 application to grails 3 I am facing some weird situation as:
I have two domain named **Service.groovy** and **Test.groovy**. Test domain has **hasMany** relation with Service e.g static hasMany = [services: Service]. 
Now while running the application it throws exception as

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in
>   testproject.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]:
>   Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception;
>   nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.Service
>   cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

I have created test project in grails 3 and it seems like **new grails** is not excepting Service.groovy as domain.

Please Kindly suggest.

Comment: Does the exception get thrown if the domains are renamed to something other than 'Service' and 'Test'?

Comment: actually not, if i change the domain name from Service.groovy to Test.groovy it works fine. I am migrating the existing application so it created issue. But for now i am working after renaming the domain name.

Comment: you can answer your own question.  It might be useful for developers in the future who encounter your issue